# Issue with local variables in r custom function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, custom-function

I've got a dataset

```
>view(interval)
#   V1 V2 V3 ID
# 1 NA 1  2  1
# 2 2  2  3  2
# 3 3  NA 1  3
# 4 4  2  2  4
# 5 NA 5  1  5

>dput(interval)
structure(list(V1 = c(NA, 2, 3, 4, NA),
V2 = c(1, 2, NA, 2, 5),
V3 = c(2, 3, 1, 2, 1), ID = 1:5), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to extract the previous not NA value (or the next, if NA is in the first row) for every row, and store it as a local variable in a custom function, because I have to perform other operations on every row based on this value(which should change for every row i'm applying the function).
I've written this function to print the local variables, but when I apply it the output is not what I want

```
myFunction<- function(x){
              position <- as.data.frame(which(is.na(interval), arr.ind=TRUE))
              tempVar <- ifelse(interval$ID == 1, interval[position$row+1,
                         position$col], interval[position$row-1, position$col])
              return(tempVar)
}
```

I was expecting to get something like this

```
# [1]    2
# [2]    2
# [3]    4
```

But I get something pretty messed up instead.

Comment: Could you provide `interval` using `dput` function to make it easier for SO community to help you?

Comment: I don't understand how your intended output is usable. If the function returns a vector of (in this case) three values, how do you know what to do with them without re-determining which indices they refer to? How do you know that the first `2` should reference an `NA` in the first row, the second `2` to the third row, etc? I guess I understand what you are asking for but not what you need or plan to do with it.

Comment: @r2evans well, I'm not interested in that particular output. I wanted to show the values of the three desired local variables for every iteration of my function

Comment: What happens when you have two `NA` stacked?

Comment: @r2evans in the actual dataset there aren't consecutive NAs, anyway in that case I can edit my function to get the first not NA value available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's attempt number 1:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
V1 V2 V3 ID
NA 1  2  1
2  2  3  2
3  NA 1  3
4  2  2  4
NA 5  1  5')
myfunc1 <- function(x) {
  ind <- which(is.na(x), arr.ind=TRUE)
  # since it appears you want them in row-first sorted order
  ind <- ind[order(ind[,1], ind[,2]),]
  # catch first-row NA
  ind[,1] <- ifelse(ind[,1] == 1L, 2L, ind[,1] - 1L)
  x[ind]
}
myfunc1(dat)
# [1] 2 2 4
```

The problem with this is when there is a second "stacked" `NA`:

```
dat2 <- dat
dat2[2,1] <- NA
dat2
#   V1 V2 V3 ID
# 1 NA  1  2  1
# 2 NA  2  3  2
# 3  3 NA  1  3
# 4  4  2  2  4
# 5 NA  5  1  5
myfunc1(dat2)
# [1] NA NA  2  4
```

One fix/safeguard against this is to use `zoo::na.locf`, which takes the "`l`ast `o`bservation `c`arried `f`orward". Since the top-row is a special case, we do it twice, second time in reverse. This gives us the "next non-`NA` value in the column (up or down, depending).

```
library(zoo)
myfunc2 <- function(x) {
  ind <- which(is.na(x), arr.ind=TRUE)
  # since it appears you want them in row-first sorted order
  ind <- ind[order(ind[,1], ind[,2]),]
  # this is to guard against stacked NA
  x <- apply(x, 2, zoo::na.locf, na.rm = FALSE)
  # this special-case is when there are one or more NAs at the top of a column
  x <- apply(x, 2, zoo::na.locf, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
  x[ind]
}
myfunc2(dat2)
# [1] 3 3 2 4
```